# JS & Lodash array find and delete methods

Tags: javascript, lodash

Say I have an array in js:

```
let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
```

1. How would I search through the array and check if the `'three'` element exists in the array and return true/false.
2. How would I delete the a given element, (ex. 'two') from the array.

Are there lodash methods for this?

Comment: Why lodash? `arr.includes("three")`, `.splice(1, 1)`, `.splice(arr.findIndex("two"), 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need lodash:

```js
arr.includes("three") // true
arr.includes("five") // false

// the 1 means to delete one element
arr.splice(arr.indexOf("two"), 1)
arr // ["one", "three", "four"]
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need lodash to achieve these functionality?
Depends. Using lodash equivalents could be beneficial in order to apply functional composition together with other lodash functions.

**Vanilla JS Implementation:**

```
const targetValue = 'four';
const exampleArray = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

// 1) checks whether the exampleArray contains targetValue
exampleArray.includes(targetValue);

// 2) creates a new array without targetValue
const exampleArrayWithoutTargetValue =
  exampleArray.filter((value) => value !== targetValue);
```

**Using lodash:**

```
const targetValue = 'four';
const exampleArray = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five'];

// 1)
// https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#includes
_.includes(exampleArray, targetValue);

// 2)
// https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter
const exampleArrayWithoutTargetValue =
  _.filter(exampleArray, (value) => value !== targetValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if element exist in array

```
arr.inclues("three") //true
```

In case you want to start search from index 3

```
arr.inclues("three",3) //false
```

2.Delete a given element

```js
let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']
const index = arr.indexOf('two')
if (index > -1) {
  arr.splice(index, 1);
}
console.log(arr)
```

Delete all occurance of given value

```js
let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four','two']
let value = 'two'
arr = arr.filter(item => item !== value)
console.log(arr)
```

If more than one value needed to delete

```js
let arr = ['one', 'two', 'three', 'four']

let toDelete = ['one','three']

arr = arr.filter(item => !toDelete.includes(item))
console.log(arr)
```